# Most efficient way to loop through a file's values and check a dictionary for any/all corresponding instances

Tags: python, csv

I have a file with user's names, one per line, and I need to compare each name in the file to all values in a csv file and make note each time the user name appears in the csv file. I need to make the search as efficient as possible as the csv file is 40K lines long

My example persons.txt file:

```
Smith, Robert
Samson, David
Martin, Patricia
Simpson, Marge
```

My example locations.csv file:

```
GreaterLocation,LesserLocation,GroupName,DisplayName,InBook
NorthernHemisphere,UnitedStates,Pilots,"Wilbur, Andy, super pilot",Yes
WesternHemisphere,China,Pilots,"Kirby, Mabry, loves pizza",Yes
WesternHemisphere,Japan,Drivers,"Samson, David, big kahuna",Yes
NortherHemisphere,Canada,Drivers,"Randos, Jorge",Yes
SouthernHemispher,Australia,Mechanics,"Freeman, Gordon",Yes
NortherHemisphere,Mexico,Pilots,"Simpson, Marge",Yes
SouthernHemispher,New Zealand,Mechanics,"Samson, David",Yes
```

My Code:

```
import csv

def parse_files():

    with open('data_file/persons.txt', 'r') as user_list:
        lines = user_list.readlines()
        for user_row in lines:
            new_user = user_row.strip()
            per = []
            with open('data_file/locations.csv', newline='') as target_csv:
                DictReader_loc = csv.DictReader(target_csv)
            
                for loc_row in DictReader_loc:
                    if new_user.lower() in loc_row['DisplayName'].lower():
                        per.append(DictReader_loc.line_num)
                        print(DictReader_loc.line_num, loc_row['DisplayName'])
            if len(per) > 0:
                print("\n"+new_user, per)
    print("Parse Complete")
        
def main():
    parse_files()

main()
```

My code currently works. Based on the sample data in the example files, the code matches the 2 instances of "Samson, David" and 1 instance of "Simpson, Marge" in the locations.csv file. I'm hoping that someone can give me guidance on how I might transform either the persons.txt file or the locations.csv file (40K+ lines) so that the process is as efficient as it can be. I think it currently takes 10-15 minutes. I know looping isn't the most efficient, but I do need to check each name and see where it appears in the csv file.

Comment: A quick improvement would be to read `data_file/locations.csv` only once (at the beginning of the function). No need to open & re-read for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but wasn't able to get it working correctly. I use the open method and then csv.DictReader(), maybe my placement wasn't correct. The one time I did get it to work, it only looped through the first person in the list. Could you show an example?

Comment: Your sample CSV shows that DisplayName also has other data, like nicknames, e.g., “super pilot”. Should that data be part of the search?

Comment: No, I put that there because the real data in that field consists of different length strings. But all the data in that field starts off the same, with the user's last name, a comma, then the user's first name, then maybe more information, but not always. I will update the examples data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Tomalak's solution with SQLite is very useful, but if you want to keep it closer to your original code, see the version below.

Effectively, it reduces the amount of file opening/closing/reading that is going on, and hopefully will speed things up.

Since your sample is very small, I could not do any real measurements.

Going forward, you can consider using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) for these kind of tasks - it can be very convenient working with CSVs and more optimized than the csv module.

```
import csv

def parse_files():
    with open('persons.txt', 'r') as user_list:
        # sets are faster to match against than lists
        # do the lower() here to avoid repetition
        user_set  = set([u.strip().lower() for u in user_list.readlines()])
    # open file at beginning, close after done
    # you could also encapsulate the whole thing into a `with` clause if
    # desired
    target_csv = open("locations.csv", "r", newline='')
    DictReader_loc = csv.DictReader(target_csv)
    for user in user_set:
        per = []
        for loc_row in DictReader_loc:
            if user in loc_row['DisplayName'].lower():
                per.append(DictReader_loc.line_num)
                print(DictReader_loc.line_num, loc_row['DisplayName'])
        if len(per) > 0:
            print("\n"+user, per)
    print("Parse Complete")
    target_csv.close()
        
def main():
    parse_files()

main()
```